# How to use load with nested objects in marshmallow-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm using marshmallow-sqlalchemy with flask extension and trying to use the load method of my ModelSchema class.
I have something like this:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
ma = Marshmallow()

#I'm using Application Factorie
def create_app():
    ...
    db.init_app(app)
    ma.init_app(app)
    ...
    return app


class BaseSchema(ma.ModelSchema):    
    class Meta:
        sqla_session = db.session  

class Parent(db.Model):    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)
    child_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("child.id"), nullable=False)
    child = db.relationship("Child")

class ParentSchema(BaseSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
    child = ma.Nested("ChildSchema")

class Child(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False)

class ChildSchema(BaseSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
```

Overall works perfectly, queries, inserts... But when I try to load a new parent object with a existing child in data base like: `new_parent = ParentSchema().load({'name':'Foo', 'child' : {'id':1,'name':'Bar'} })` returns it `AttributeError: 'DummySession' object has no attribute 'query'`.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I THINK that your BaseSchema's Meta class isn't being inherited properly.

Change this

```
class ParentSchema(BaseSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
```

to this

```
class ParentSchema(BaseSchema):
    class Meta(BaseSchema.Meta):
        model = Parent
```

Reference:  https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html (Base Schema I example)